# Read Dynamic UserForm Checkboxes and Populate Array

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a userform that I populate dynamically -

```
For Each J In Temp
    Set Cbx = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1")
    Cbx.Caption = J
    Cbx.Left = 15
    Cbx.Top = 15 + (17.5 * (Cntr - 1))
    Cntr = Cntr + 1
Next J

Cntr = 15 + (17.5 * (Cntr - 1)) + 50

UserForm1.CommandButton1.Top = Cntr - 35
```

I also have a command button as can be seen from the last line of the code snippet.

When I click the command button, I want to populate an array with the `Caption` of the checkboxes that are checked.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call Summary
End Sub

Sub Summary()

    Dim Num As Integer
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim FltrTypes() As Double

    Num = UserForm1.Controls.Count - 1

    ReDim Preserve FltrTypes(0)

    For I = 0 To (Num - 1)
        If Left(UserForm1.Controls(I).Name, 8) = "CheckBox" Then
            If UserForm1.Controls(I).Value = "True" Then
                FltrTypes(I) = UserForm1.Controls(I).Caption
            End If
        End If
    Next I

End Sub
```

But the array is not populating. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: shouldn't `ReDim Preserve FltrTypes(0)` be something like `ReDim Preserve FltrTypes(Num)`?

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 The array still does not populate.

Comment: when you debug it does it ever fill anything into the array? are you using the locals window/breakpoints to check?

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 Yes, I am using locals and breakpoints, which is how I can see the array FltrTypes is  {0, 0, 0..}.

Comment: could it be that filtertypes is double and not a string? not sure what type your caption actually is

Comment: They are `Variant/String`

Comment: then you might want to change to `Dim FltrTypes() As` **`String`**

Comment: FltrTypes is now {"", "", ""...}.

Comment: so does it print values if you add the line `Debug.Print UserForm1.Controls(I).Caption` above the assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is this:

```
If UserForm1.Controls(I).Value = "True" Then
```

without quotes

```
If UserForm1.Controls(I).Value = True Then
```

`FltrTpye` must be `String` not `Double`
however there are many little errors, the code rewritten:

```
Dim Num As Integer
Dim I As Integer
Dim FltrTypes() As String
Dim NFltrTypes As Long

Num = UserForm1.Controls.Count - 1

Erase FltrTypes
NFltrTypes = 0
For I = 0 To (Num - 1)
    If Left(UserForm1.Controls(I).Name, 8) = "CheckBox" Then
        If UserForm1.Controls(I).Value = True Then
            ReDim Preserve FltrTypes(NFltrTypes)
            NFltrTypes = NFltrTypes + 1
            FltrTypes(NFltrTypes - 1) = UserForm1.Controls(I).Caption
        End If
    End If
Next I
```